# Return Statement positioning

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement, vector, return

I am writing some function which basically takes in input a range and a 1D vector. It looks at each number in the range of values given of the vector such that:

1) If the number to the left of it is 0 they swap positions.

2) If the number to the left of it is equal to it they add.

Now up till now this was good. The issue arises when I am trying to **add return statements:**

1) It should return True after **all** iterations are complete and at least one of the if conditions is entered in each iteration.

2) It should return false after **all** iterations are complete and none of the conditions are entered.

Now if I put these return statements in the loops they would terminate this function here but this is not desirable since it needs to go through all the iterations first. Is the current code comparable with this or do I need to redo it in a different manner ( if not where could the return statements go?)

Comment: The return statement goes at the end of the function (where else could it go as you must complete the loops). You add a boolean variable to your code which tracks whether the eventual return value should be true or false.

Comment: Actually they do not swap, as you overwrite at j with value at i and then assign it back. After that, both positions hold value of j. Consider using `std::swap(v[j], v[i])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool proc_num(std::vector<int>&v, int LB, int UB) {            
    bool check = false;
    for( int i=LB+2 ; i<UB; i++) {
        for(int j = i-1; j>LB; j--) {
            if(v[j] == 0){
                v[j] = v[i];
                check = true;
            } else if(v[j] == v[i]) {
                v[j]= v[j]+v[i];
                v[i] = 0;
                check = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return check;
}
```

You can simply add a boolean to make sure that at least one of the if conditions are entered.